# Ros, iai_kinect2 issues

Tags: ros, kinect

here is what I did on **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** running on a Toshiba Satellite, **intel** i7, **nvidia** with **usb 3.0 and 2.0 ports**.

1, 2, 3 refer to scripts found [here](https://github.com/Parth-Mehrotra/Tools/tree/master/InstallScripts)

1. Setup ros by running this install-ros.sh script
2. Setup opencv by running this install-opencv.sh script
3. Setup PCL by running this install-pcl.sh script
4. Installed  libfreenect2 via the instructions at the master branch
5. Made the changes and installed
6. Cloned the repository into an empty catkin workspace
7. Sourced the respective setup.zsh files from my **/opt/ros/...** and from the **devel/** folders.

At this point, I have encountered no issues

I tried running:

```
rosrun kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge
```

and I get the following message:

```
[ERROR] [1424391698.413758209]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying..
```

So I assume I need to run roscore or something like that. So if I run:

```
roscore
```

in one terminal and:

```
rosrun kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge
```

in another terminal, I get the following segmentation fault:

```
[ERROR] [1424393345.496836066]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
[ INFO] [1424393446.243884489]: Connected to master at [localhost:11311]
parameter:
        base_name: kinect2
           sensor: 
        fps_limit: -1
       calib_path: /home/parthmehrotra/catkin_ws/src/iai_kinect2/kinect2_bridge/data/
          use_png: false
     jpeg_quality: 90
        png_level: 1
     depth_method: opengl
     depth_device: -1
       reg_method: default
       reg_devive: -1
        max_depth: 12
        min_depth: 0.1
       queue_size: 2
 bilateral_filter: true
edge_aware_filter: true
       publish_tf: false
     base_name_tf: kinect2
   worker_threads: 4

[1]    2679 segmentation fault (core dumped)  rosrun kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge
```

I must be overlooking something really trivial. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: You might have better luck at answers.ros.org

Comment: Are you sure your kinect is detected and working on your Ubuntu ? I had lots of trouble getting my Xtion to work correctly. As well where do you find those install scripts ? It appears that having PCL installed from PCL repos isn't working with ros ! You need to install PCL from ros repos.

Comment: @Malc If I run something like lsusb, the Kinect shows up. I created those scripts, but I retried by simply following the instructions found on the ROS repositories so that's not the issue. Is lsusb sufficient evidence that kinect is detected by Ubuntu?

Comment: I can't say for sure. I did that a long time ago. Do you have any "test scripts" for the kinect ? Something outside ros that when you launch it, shows the camera image

Comment: Nothing that was successfully run. I received segmentation faults on the libfreenect2 demos as well

Comment: So, that's probably not a ROS related problem. How did you install libfreenect ?